# Fatal error when committing changes to git from visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-commit

So everything was working fine, until yesterday I wrote some code and pushed, but nothing changed in GitHub, so I came and added a comment line and commited then it said fatal error :

**Git failed with a fatal error.
error: invalid object 100644 342bad3922f69c8ae111f019ceffc916dd4982cb for 'DataAccess/Concrete/EntityFramework/EfColorDal.cs'
error: bad tree object HEAD**

first the path was pointing to another class, I deleted and wrote it again, and when I committed again it showed this class this time, I figured it would just keep going.
and when I run out of everything to try from internet, I decided to restart, upon opening again it said Fixing errors in D disk, where is my solution is placed. It was fixing for like an hour, when it finally ended, nothing changed.

I used gitbash console to execute the codes
when I run codes like git --fsck it said:

**Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.**

**notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)**

**notice: No default references**

**missing tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904**

As I dont know anything about git coding, I tried some more stuff previous posts suggested, but none of it worked. My local repository is in C disk and it holds the code before yesterday, so I could write the code again, but there is no guarantee it wont happen again, so Im open to any help offered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> upon opening again ***it*** said Fixing errors in D disk

What "it" is this?  I presume "it" was your operating system.

> It was fixing for like an hour, when it finally ended, nothing changed.

I think several things *had* changed at this point.  When your OS tries to "fix" problems on a file system due to unexpected power failures, or disk errors, or other hardware problems, one of the things your OS will do is *remove various files*.  Essentially, the OS discovers that while some file was *created* (so that it appears to be valid), it was never *finished* (so it actually isn't valid).  The OS's solution to this problem is to remove the file.

Meanwhile, Git itself is extremely sensitive to certain file-removals.  Several after-crash removals are common, and each one breaks Git in a specific way.  The `git fsck` command checks for this kind of damage (among others):

- Removal of a file containing branch data can produce messages such as `notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)`.
- Removal of a file containing an internal tree or blob object can produce messages about missing tree and/or blob objects.

These are the two messages that your Git has produced here, so we can conclude that something damaged, perhaps irrecoverably, the repository on the `D:` drive.

> My local repository is in C disk and it holds the code before yesterday ...

The GitHub copies of the repository will probably also be intact, and will be as up-to-date as you made them.  That's why (or perhaps a better adverb is *how*) Git, as a distributed system, is pretty resilient: even if multiple copies of the repository are destroyed, other copies remain fine.

> so I could write the code again, but there is no guarantee it wont happen again ...

Indeed.  What is it about the `D:` drive that caused it to become damaged to the point that the Git repository did not work and the OS decided to repair it?  **Git** is not the issue here.  Rather, the `D:` drive is.

Comment: Sorry, I was moving to another apartment, I could just come back.

Comment: So I guess I need to write the code again on top of the local C repository, and just delete the solution from D: drive?

Comment: Actually, this kinda crash also happened when I used Unity+ Visual Studio, I changed to VS Code and it didn`t happen again, its been a few months until then, I thought it wouldnt happen again if I used VS without any other apps like Unity, I guess I was wrong then, how can I know what is the issue with my drive?

Comment: I don't know the answers to those things: I don't use any of those GUIs; perhaps one of them is broken?